# AWS CDK: Uploaded file must be a non-empty zip

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-cloud9

I have written a simple hello world lambda function to deploy but after the command `cdk deploy` it is giving this error. Can someone please guide about this?

[image]

Comment: Well the error message says you have uploaded an empty zip file.

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65916681/uploaded-file-must-be-a-non-empty-zip-service-awslambdainternal-status-code?

Answer (score 4):

Steps helps to resolve it...

- delete cdk.out (directory)
- run command

  - cdk synth
  - cdk bootstrap
  - cdk deploy

Answer (score 3):

This issue might be caused by https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/12536. You should try:

1. Upgrading node.js version
2. Deleting `cdk.out`
3. Upgrade to latest CDK version
4. Delete the asset directly from S3 (bucket will be something like `cdk-hnb659fds-assets-<ACCOUNT NUMBER>-<REGION>`)
5. Deploy again

CDK doesn't reupload the asset unless it changed. That's why deleting it and maybe forcing a change after upgrading node.js is required.

If all else fails, try [the script](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/12536#issuecomment-885988964) I wrote that downloads the asset, fixes it by rezipping, and uploads it again. It's expecting to run in the root of your project as it looks for `cdk.out`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY=`jq -r '.artifacts[] | select(.type == "cdk:cloud-assembly") | .properties.directoryName' cdk.out/manifest.json`
ASSET_MANIFESTS=`jq -r '.artifacts[] | select(.type == "cdk:asset-manifest") | .properties.file' cdk.out/$ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY/manifest.json`
cd cdk.out/$ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY
ASSETS=`jq -r '.files[].destinations[] | "s3://" + .bucketName + "/" + .objectKey' $ASSET_MANIFESTS | grep zip`

TMP=`mktemp -d`
cd $TMP

for ASSET in $ASSETS
do
    if aws s3 ls $ASSET; then
        aws s3 cp $ASSET pkg.zip
        mkdir s
        cd s
        if ! unzip ../pkg.zip; then echo bad zip; fi
        rm ../pkg.zip
        zip -r ../pkg.zip * .gitempty
        aws s3 cp ../pkg.zip $ASSET
        cd ..
        rm -rf s
    fi
done

rm -rf $TMP
```

You can confirm you're having the same issue I was having by downloading the asset zip file. Try extracting it with `unzip`. If it complains about the checksum or CRC, you had the same issue.

Comment: Making a change to my TypeScript lambda and then redeploying fixed this issue for me

Comment: Thanks! Was running around in circles trying to fix this for the past couple days.  Making a change to my lambda python function also fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it occurred in WSL2.

It turned out it was introduced when I accidentaly `npm i`ed in windows console.

Solution was then:

#### in WSL2:

- `rm -r node_modules`
- `rm -r cdk.out`
- `npm i`
- `cdk synth`

Then `cdk deploy` worked as expected. No bootstrapping necessary.